# String timestamp to int, make a DateTime with it afterwards in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I want to know if a timestamp stored in my database as a bigint (I'm using mariaDB) is already old comparing it to the current date, there's one example:

I have this timestamp stored in my `db = 1560499685530` but for some reason, it is a string when I fetch it from my db so I got this error when trying to set its timestamp (setTimestamp($timestamp))

> DateTime::setTimestamp() expects parameter 1 to be integer, string
>   given

I tried using `intval` but my timestamp seems to be too long to be `int` because when I use `inval` it returns another int, smaller than mine, I guess that's the PHP int cap

I want my PHP to print if it's already an old date comparing it to the current date and wrote this code

```
$qBloqueo = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM dates WHERE idUsuario = '$idUsuario'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$timestamp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qBloqueo);
$timestamp = intval($timestamp['timestamp']); // Getting the timestamp from my db which is a string, still dunno why, in my db it's a bigint

$today = new DateTime();
$expireDate = new DateTime();
$expireDate->setTimestamp($timestamp);

if($today->format("Y-m-d") > $expireDate->format("Y-m-d")) { 
    print('Old date ^u^');
} else {
    print('Not yet');
}
```

How can I use a timestamp to make a date obj without been a int or there is any way to convert it from a string to int? I just want to make a date from a string timestamp so I could compare it to the current date

Comment: What kind of timestamp is `1560499685530`? Are those milliseconds? If those are seconds  your date is WAY into the future. Are you sure that's you intention? Are you trying to save a date hundreds or thousand of years into the future?

Comment: "_if a timestamp stored in my database as a bigint_" As bigint? Why not `timestamp`?

Comment: I think so, It's not so weird as you put it, I visited https://www.epochconverter.com then wrote that timestamp and got a valid and pretty date: Friday, 14 June 2019 8:08:05.530, so it guess those are indeed miliseconds

Comment: I... I didn't knew theres was an special datatype for timestamps, I will give it a try, thank you

Comment: Well, it's weird because `setTimestamp()` expects a number of seconds, and you are passing a number of milliseconds. Logically, it doesn't work as expected. Just divide by 1000 before passing the value to `setTimestamp()`.

Comment: See if https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/timestamp/ can help

Comment: Dividing it by 1000 was all that I needed, thank you yivi
Thanks for you help kerbholz c:

Answer (score -1):

If only type is concern then you can type cast variable like:

`$timestamp = (int) $timestamp['timestamp'];`

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for difference between two times

```
<?php 

$time1 = new DateTime('09:00:59');
$time2 = new DateTime('09:01:00');
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);
echo $interval->format('%s second(s)');
?> 

Output :
1 second(s)
```

Now to find difference between two timestamps

```
/* PHP/5.5.8 and later */
$start = new DateTimeImmutable('2016-04-20 00:37:15');
$end = $start->modify('+7 days');
$diff = $end->diff($start);
print_r($diff);

Output : 
DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 0 [d] => 7 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [f] => 0 [weekday] => 0 [weekday_behavior] => 0 [first_last_day_of] => 0 [invert] => 1 [days] => 7 [special_type] => 0 [special_amount] => 0 [have_weekday_relative] => 0 [have_special_relative] => 0 )
```

To convert date timestamp into millisecond

```
$yourdate = '2016-03-22 14:30';
$stamp = strtotime($yourdate); // get unix timestamp
$time_in_ms = $stamp*1000;
print_r($time_in_ms);

Output : 
1458657000000
```

You can convert both times into millisecond and find which one is greater. 
I hope this helps in some way